# Как получить значение выбранной строки из ListView?

Tags: android, delphi, listview, firemonkey, delphi-10-seattle

Как получить значение выбранной строки из ListView?

Comment: Хотя бы код покажите какой-то. Так-то выбрав строку вы получаете её порядковый номер и по нему из массива данных для списка получаете значение. Либо даже оно в колбэк придёт. Всё зависит от кода/реализации

Comment: кое-какой текст вернет вам `ListView.Selected.Text` или `Listview.Selected.Details`

Comment: возможно надо привести к `TListViewItem(ListView.Selected).Text`

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку речь идет о `FMX`, а не `VCL`, то согласно [документации](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/FMX.ListView.TListView_Properties) для получения выбранного элемента списка следует использовать свойство `Selected` (если ничего не выбрано, возвращает `nil`).
В целом, говоря об этом фреймворке, ваши элементы списка могут выглядеть вообще как угодно и содержать любые данные. Но в стандартном виде для получения текста элемента следует использовать [свойство `Text`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/FMX.ListView.TListViewBase.Selected)

```
SelectedItemText := TListViewItem(TListView1.Selected).Text;
```

Также имеется [свойство `detail`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/FMX.ListView.Appearances.TListViewItem.Detail) для доп. текста.